# Precision of Math.Cos() for a large integer

Tags: c#, floating-point

I'm trying to compute the cosine of 4203708359 radians in C#:

```
var x = (double)4203708359;
var c = Math.Cos(x);
```

(4203708359 can be exactly represented in double precision.)

I'm getting

```
c = -0.57977754519440394
```

Windows' calculator gives

```
c = -0.579777545198813380788467070278
```

PHP's `cos(double)` function (which internally just uses `cos(double)` from the C standard library) on Linux gives:

```
c = -0.57977754519881
```

C's `cos(double)` function in a simple C program compiled with Visual Studio 2017 gives

```
c = -0.57977754519881342
```

Here is the definition of `Math.cos()` in C#: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Math.cs#L57-L58

It appears to be a built-in function. I didn't dig (yet) in the C# compiler to check what this effectively compiles to but this is probably the next step.

In the meantime:

**Why is the precision so poor in my C# example, and what can I do about it?**

Is it simply that the cosine implementation in the C# compiler deals poorly with large integer inputs?

Edit 1: Wolfram Mathematica 11.0:

```
In[1] := N[Cos[4203708359], 50]
Out[1] := -0.57977754519881338078846707027800171954257546099993
```

Edit 2: I do need that level precision, and I'm ready to go *pretty far* in order to obtain it. I'd be happy to use an arbitrary precision library if there exists a good one that supports cosine (my efforts haven't led to one so far).

Edit 3: I posted the question on coreclr's issue tracker: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12737

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do with Math to increase precision. In general, it's better to use decimal for high-precision calculations, but Math doesn't support it.

Comment: I mean, the precision isn't *that* poor.  That's still quite a lot of digits there.  Is that actually not enough precision for whatever it is that you're working with?

Comment: Python gives 

`[In]: math.cos(4203708359)`


`[Out]: -0.5797775451988134`

Are you sure Wolfram Alpha is correct?

Comment: @MickyD Yes, it appears to be, because as I pointed out `Math.Cos()` is declared as a form of intrinsic and I suppose converted to machine code by the JIT compiler, i.e. in the C# compiler. In other words it's not a library function. It's a common approach in most C/C++ compilers, a lot of functions are built-in.

Comment: @Servy I need more precision, unfortunately.

Comment: I am with Servy, the difference is less than 0.000000001%.  When dealing with floats, and specially when you add trigonometric functions, you really should not expect any better precision.  If you do, you'd better start working with decimals, not floats, and probably will have to implement your own trig functions.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I'm ready to go _pretty far_ to have more precision, including using an arbitrary precision library. Anyone has one to suggest that supports cosines?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune: "converted to machine code by the JIT compiler" -- correct.  "i.e. in the C# compiler" -- nope.  The C# compiler takes in textual C# code and generates intermediate language.  It doesn't know anything about machine code (and the intermediate language can be taken to a different device with a different CPU architecture and possibly no machine instructions for trig operations at all.  On many platforms `cos()` really is a library function with heavy software implementation.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, that's what I meant. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use-case - CERN is the first thing that comes to mind.  Something similar?

Comment: @AgapwIesu Ahah, I wish it was ;) It's much less sexy unfortunately. We need to reimplement in C# a *moronic* legacy password hashing routine (originally implemented in PHP) that appends the cosine of the salt to an otherwise reasonably industry-standard hashing routine. Sorry for the disappointment :)

Comment: Oh, then you don't care about precision, you care about perfectly (down to the last bit) replicating the output of some other implementation (which might itself be terribly inaccurate)

Comment: I'd suspect an x87 vs. SSE problem. Did you compile the code for the same target (x86 or x86-64)?

Comment: @BenVoigt is exactly right, in which case, Yikes!  You have one pickle of a problem.

Comment: What's the size of the space of salts?  If its tractable then you could simply compute all the cosines of all the salts using the original PHP implementation, put them in a database, and call it done.

Comment: Whaaa! That is indeed *moronic*. As @BenVoigt says, you'll have to implement the exact same (possibly inaccurate) code giving the exact same values. That may be nearly impossible. Does the original code still work (do you still have that version of PHP that produces the cosines? -- you may be able to reverse engineer the algorithm).

Comment: @BenVoigt While you're right that I don't actually care about precision but about the bit-accurate result, I'm rather optimistic because the PHP version ends up using the C version of cos() as implemented in gcc/libm which appears to give the correct first 14 decimals (at least for all inputs I've tried).

Comment: Duplicating the inherent error of the PHP calculation, in C#, will be impossible. The only viable solution I see is to do what @EricLippert suggests, but also supersede this hashing algorith with a new one.  That would require that you also store a password version number that indicates whether the password hash is from the old set, or your new implementation.

Comment: @EricLippert Oh I hadn't thought about precomputing :) Unfortunately the salt space is too large for this to be a practical solution, but I appreciate the out-of-the-box thinking!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes we have the old code and have reimplemented it in C#, the only problem is the precision of the cosine. Did you mean reimplementing gcc/libm's cos() function in C#? That would be an (expensive) idea :)

Comment: presumably, the salts are stored with the password, yes?  If so, you don't have to calculate the cosine of every possible salt, only the cosine of the salts in the password database.  With the PHP code, calculate the cosine of every salt and store that also into the database.

Comment: @AgapwIesu They are, and this is a _great_ suggestion.

Comment: @EricLippert - You should make that an answer, Eric.  It **is** a really good idea.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune: Yes, I meant reimplementing the "original" cosine function in C#. Not as expensive as you think, and if the number of possible salt values is limited then you can do what Eric Lippert says: generate all possible corresponding cosines (possibly using the original PHP) and store them in a database or otherwise.

Comment: @EOF I doubt that C# JIT uses FP but I haven't verified. VS 2014 uses a complicated SSE2-based implementation (I checked) and PHP on Linux is probably compiled with gcc and thus uses libm's complicated implementation here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;h=c258d39e494b009963f35da92d12fcad60a325db;hb=HEAD. I don't think any modern compiler emits `fcos` or `fsincos` anymore.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Eric's idea is simple but indeed very clever. What makes it practical is your idea of only precomputing it for the actual salts. In fact I think I'll give it a try. Feel free to post an answer as well!

Comment: And yes, this is an absolutely crazy thing to do. I have seen so many shenanigans with misuse of hash functions, and many of them come down to the problem shown here: **the output of a hash function is logically not a number**, so don't treat it as a number. It's a *string of bits*; just because you *can* treat a string of bits as an integer doesn't mean that it logically *is* an integer.

Comment: @MickyD Could you point me to the source code of that method? My point is that while it is _declared_ in System (as an intrinsic), it is not _defined_ there. But I may be mistaking.

Comment: @MickyD From https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12737, `Math.Cos()` appears to be wired here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/13e7c4368da664a8b50228b1a5ef01a660fbb2dd/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L661 and implemented here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/395f145ba0c220afb1d85ff8c26f34909d8ea424/src/classlibnative/float/floatdouble.cpp#L102-L106

Comment: If C code gets the correct result, have you considered using p/invoke to call either (a) the `cos()` function in the C library DLL, or (b) a tiny C DLL which calls `cos()` (the latter may be necessary if you get correct results from an intrinsic but not the library)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes that's exactly what I ended up doing! I was about to write a wrap-up in the other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030449.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might know the answer.  I'm pretty sure the sin/cos libraries don't take arbitrarily large numbers and calculate the sin/cos of them - they instead reduce them down to low numbers (between 0-2xpi?) and calculate them there.  I mean, cos(x) = cos(x + 2xpi) = cos(x + 4xpi) = ...

Problem is, how is the program supposed to reduce your 10-digit number down?  Realistically, it should figure out how many times it needs to multiply (2xpi) to get a value just below your number, then subtract that out.  In your case, that's about 670 million.

So it's multiplying (2xpi) by this 9 digit value - so it's effectively losing 9 digits worth of significance from the math library's version of pi.

I ended up writing a little function to test what was going on:

```
    private double reduceDown(double start)
    {

        decimal startDec = (decimal)start;
        decimal pi = decimal.Parse("3.1415926535897932384626433832795");
        decimal tau = pi * 2;
        int num = (int)(startDec / tau);
        decimal x = startDec - (num * tau);
        double retVal;
        double.TryParse(x.ToString(), out retVal);
        return retVal;
        //return start - (num * tau);
    }
```

All this is doing is using decimal data type as a way of reducing down the value *without* losing digits of precision from pi - it still returns back a double.  When I call it with a modification of your code:

```
        var x = (double)4203708359;
        var c = Math.Cos(x);

        double y = reduceDown(x);
        double c2 = Math.Cos(y);

        MessageBox.Show(c.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + c2);
        return;
```

... sure enough, the second one is accurate.

So my advice is - if you really need radians that high, and you really need the accuracy?  Do something like that function above, and reduce the number down on your end in a way that you don't lose digits of precision.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks for the investigation. At the end of the day, the robustness of this method might not be sufficient, but I really appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the salts are stored along with each password.  You could use the PHP code to calculate that cosine, and store that also with the password.  I would then also add a password version number and default all those older passwords to be version 1.  Then, in your C# code, for any new passwords, you implement a new hashing algorithm, and store those password hashes as passwords version 2.  For any version 1 passwords, to authenticate, you do not have to calculate the cosine, you simply use the one stored along with the password hash and the salt.

The programmer of that PHP code was probably wanting to do a clever version of pepper.  By storing that cosine, or pepper along with the salt and the password hashes, you basically change that pepper into a salt2.  So, another versionless way of doing this would be to use two salts in your C# hashing code.  For new passwords you could leave the second salt blank or assign it some other way.  For old passwords, it would be that cosine, but it is already calculated.

Comment: While it is not your fault that the OP didn't bother to ask the question they _really_ wanted the answer to, this answer does not in _any way_ address the question that was asked and should not be posted here. The OP should post a new question that describes the _actual problem_, where you can post this answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're completely right, my bad. My question regarding the accuracy of `Math.Cos()` in C# still stand and I think (I have to test) that the other answer by Kevin is relevant. Should I now create another question with the actual problem at hand, and have Agapwlesu answer there?

Comment: _"Should I now create another question with the actual problem at hand, and have Agapwlesu answer there?"_ -- IMHO, that would be a good solution, yes. It's possible the question you did ask here could be considered useful, and maybe even garner applicable answers, so you may want to leave this question open as well.

Comment: I posted a better framed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030449. AgapwIesu, would you mind moving this answer over there?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this part of my question: "Why is the precision so poor in my C# example", coreclr developers answered here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12737

In a nutshell, .NET Framework 4.6.2 (x86 and x64) and .NET Core (x86) appear to use Intel's x87 FP unit (i.e. `fcos` or `fsincos`) that gives inaccurate results while .NET Core on x64 (and PHP, Visual Studio 2017 and gcc) use more accurate, presumably SSE2-based implementations that give correctly rounded results.

Comment: The SSE2-based implementations may well be more accurate, but it's quite unlikely that they're correctly rounded. It might be reasonable to hope for faithfully rounded (error of no more than 1ulp), but even that would need to be quite sophisticated, needing to store and use around 1000 bits of π to do accurate argument reduction for large inputs.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You're right, but we "only" need gcc's `cos()` and VS's `cos()` to agree on the first 14 digits after the decimal point, and so far it appears that they do. Should they differ at the 14th digit, we could try a few variants (+/-1?).